# How To Share Volume With Code Files Between Two Containers In A Single Pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, cluster-shared-volumes

I created a GKE cluster and inside it I created single pod with 2 conatiners with this yaml settings.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: django-nginx
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: universal
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: universal
      mountPath: /app_api

  - name: django
    image: django
    volumeMounts:
    - name: universal
      mountPath: /app_api
```

and I'm imposting app code while building image with `Dockerfile`, part of which is here

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./app_api /app_api
```

but when I connect to container and ls into this directory, it shows no data. I want that code to be copied to that volume. how will it be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/app_api` directory is empty in both containers because you mounted emptyDir over it (it's called "empty" for reason).

You have two ways to "share" files between containers:

- Add files to both images (nginx and django) on build stage and do not use volume in pod. Technically you will have 2 different copy of data, so changes in one container will not be applied to another.
- Add [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that will copy content from image to emptyDir volume on pod start up. Something like this (note that it will not copy "dot files" from root of `/app_api/`):

  ```
  initContainers:
  - name: init
    image: nginx
    command: ["cp" "-pr" "/app_api/*" "/universal/"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: universal
      mountPath: /universal
  ```

Comment: Ty @seleznev, 1 more related query tho, I want these containers to talk to eachother, keeping in view that nginx container forwards request to django, and a services for nginx is exposed. Can I do it with single yaml file? And how would it be accomplished?